# how to change image inside sliding drawer on touch?

Tags: android

I am having an sliding drawer opening from right to left navigation when i touch the drawer icon on action bar. Working fine and closing on toggling the icon. no problem

I followed http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

In the sliding layout I have one small icon vibrate_ON.png.

Now i want when i touch the image in the sliding menu it will be changed to vibrate_OFF and so on toggling, keeping the sliding menu open.

how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
vibrateImageOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    vibrateImageOff.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    vibrateImageOn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});

vibrateImageOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    vibrateImageOn.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    vibrateImageOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

Assuming you load them both into `ImageViews` and they have equal positions, then this should work. Though, it is a bit messy..

Answer (score 0):

You can put a layout in sliding menu for more controls. To do that, you must do some step:

1) Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#fff">
    <!-- you can set any layout here -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_word"
        android:text="New words"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

2) Handle Event (plz don't forget `closeDrawer`)

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
TextView tv_word = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.tv_word );
tv_word.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);//don't forget it
        //.....
    }
});
```